# Массив Label C#

Tags: c#, label

У меня есть на форме 3 label'а. Я хочу все эти label'ы поместить в массив так, чтобы потом в цикле можно было делать что-то типа такого:
(приложение Windows Forms)

```
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    labels[i].Text="123";
```

Comment: добавьте вопрос в вопрос

Comment: Хочу сказать огромное спасибо за этот пост, я сэкономил кучу времени глянув сюда, потому что в MSDN конкретно не разобрался с коллекцией элементов управления, а вот воспользоватся массивом, это просто и быстро. Еще раз выражаю благодарность. Я начинающий программист, и мне очень хочется что-бы по больше было таких постов, где коротко и ясно. Спасибо еще раз.
С уважением Евгений evgeniy.stetsenko@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var labels = new[] { label1, label2, label3 };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Control> list_labels = new List<Control>();
list_labels.Add(label1);
list_labels.Add(label2);
list_labels.Add(label3);

for(int i = 0; i < list_labels.Count; i++)
{
    list_labels[i].Text = "123";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Label[] labels = new Label[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   labels[i] = new Label();
   labels[i].Text = i.ToString();
   this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем тебе массив?

Можно делать так, как в этом ответе:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630391/get-all-controls-of-a-specific-type

Создать метод, который будет все дергать.

Ну если тебе все таки нужен массив, то можешь почти так же их и поместить в коллекцию.